# Rails isn't sorting child elements by (cyrillic) alphabet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collation

Whatever I try, I can't make the sorting work by title. This is current output - http://take.ms/M3W2Z, basically A goes after N, B goes after A and N etc. etc.

My models:

```
class Manufacturer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  scope :by_alphabet, -> { order('title DESC' ) }
end
```

My view:

```
-@manufacturer.products.by_alphabet.each do |product|
  =product.title
```

I tried `scope :by_alphabet, -> { order('products.title DESC') }`, but it didn't help either.

Am I missing something so obvious? It's just a plain sorting... or is it an issue regarding cyrillic letters? I tried to sort a simple array with russian letters - it worked like a charm.

Comment: what is the encoding and collation of the field in table?

Comment: If I did look it up correctly: `Manufacturer.find("moroshka-sladkaya-6m").products.first.title.encoding
  Manufacturer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "manufacturers".* FROM "manufacturers" WHERE "manufacturers"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "moroshka-sladkaya-6m"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."manufacturer_id" = $1 ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["manufacturer_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>`

Answer (score 0):

When the sorting is done by the database, as in this case, you need to set a `collation` either for the query (by using the `COLLATE` keyword) or on the table (via the schema). The default collation is not likely to be the correct one for Cyrillic. You need to check what collations are available for your database, but you can probably get away with something like:

```
scope :by_alphabet, -> { order('title DESC COLLATE utf8_ru_ci' ) }
```

Consult the documentation for the database you are using for full details, as this can vary slightly from database to database.

Answer (score -1):

@manufacturer.products.sort_by(&:title)

Comment: I am back to the problem, and found my own answer that have been previously deleted. Cannot remember why this exactly happened, but this works for me again!

Comment: I suggest that you add more explanation to your answer. it has been deleted because it was seen as low quality/not an answer. People don't know if you're an expert or not, so they'll judge by the post contents.